# X11 Window Loses Active State of the Qt Window

Tags: linux, qt, x11, yocto

I have a fairly simple Application: QMainWindow with a QLineEdit and a popup menu in QMenuBar.
The Application in running on a Yocto Generic Linux with no Window Manager.
I am also writing a fairly simple Window Manager.

The **Problem** is whenever I click the MenuBar and the Popup Menu appears with multiple entries and I click away from it on the QMainWindow the Popup menu closes but the **QMainwindow is not the Active Window anymore**.
eg. The QLineEdit does not have a **Blinking Cursor** (Although I can type into it) and I have to **Click the QMainWindow one more time** to Activate the Window and have a blinking cursor.
This is not the behaviour on Ubuntu or Windows Desktop, I dont have to click one more time to make the QMainwindow the active window

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve].  In the absence of a window manager under x11 there are a *lot* of things that need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Maybe using [QApplication::focusChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged) helps to refocusing `QMainWindow`, whenever application gets distracted.